# Merge Insert Into TABLE with an PHP ARRAY and for loop

Tags: php, sql, oracle

i have an php array, coming from an database. This array i want to insert into a different db/table. Two fields (WEBINV_ID,HOSTNAME) are unique. I will update these table daily per script. If the entry exist, they must skip the insert and should use update. That's working very well. But if i run this in an php for loop, it will only insert or update the first entry of the array into the new table
I use

```
MERGE INTO TABLE ...
```

for that.
That is my input array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [CI_ID] => 39778
        [NODEALIAS] => rt-2
        [NODE] => 10.1.2.3
        [SERIALNUMBER] => 8374378584
        [VENDORNAME] => Cisco
        [STATUS] => active
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CI_ID] => 72909
        [NODEALIAS] => rt-1
        [NODE] => 10.1.1.3
        [SERIALNUMBER] => 1276731237
        [VENDORNAME] => Cisco
        [STATUS] => active
    )...
```

Here is my for loop where i try to insert or update all of my devices.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($router); $i++) {

    $sql = "MERGE INTO DEVICES USING ( SELECT "
            . "'" . $router[$i]['CI_ID'] . "' AS WEBINV_ID,"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['NODEALIAS'] . "' AS DEVICE_NAME,"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['NODE'] . "' AS NODE,"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['SERIALNUMBER'] . "' AS SERIALNUMBER,"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['VENDORNAME'] . "' AS VENDORNAME,"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['STATUS'] . "' AS STATUS,"
            . "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DEVICE_INSERT FROM DUAL
    ) S ON ('" . $router[$i]['CI_ID'] . "' = S.WEBINV_ID
         OR '" . $router[$i]['NODEALIAS'] . "' = S.DEVICE_NAME)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET STATUS = '" . $router[$i]['STATUS'] . "', DEVICE_UPDATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(WEBINV_ID,DEVICE_NAME,NODE,SERIALNUMBER,VENDORNAME,STATUS,DEVICE_INSERT)
    VALUES ('" . $router[$i]['CI_ID'] . "',"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['NODEALIAS'] . "',"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['NODE'] . "',"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['SERIALNUMBER'] . "',"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['VENDORNAME'] . "',"
            . "'" . $router[$i]['STATUS'] . "',"
            . "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

    $stid = oci_parse($gnedb, $sql);
    oci_execute($stid);  // executes and commits
}
```

I've tried the same code with "oci_bind_by_name", but the result was the same, only the first entry was used from the array. Any idea?

Comment: The fact that one record was merged shows that the sql statement is correct. Add an echo $sql; statement just before the oci_execute statement. There might be something within the data that is causing the problem. An alternative - test if the statement was actually executed by placing the necessary oci error statement after the oci_execute.

Comment: Are you sure that array contains what you think it contains?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oci_bind_by_name I understand you use Oracle database.

Maybe you should do something like this:

```
$insert_query = "insert all ";
foreach($router as $record) {
  $fields = "";
  $values = "";
  foreach($record as $field => $value) {
    $fields .= $field . ($field != 'STATUS' ? ',' : ""); // this is only if in the array the last field is STATUS - if it is not you might try to figure out last column diferently or remove last ',' differently
    $values .= "'" . $value . "'" . ($field != 'STATUS' ? ',' : ""); // this is only if in the array the last field is STATUS - if it is not you might try to figure out last column diferently or remove last ',' differently
  }
  $insert_query .= " into devices (" . $fields . ") values (" . $values . ") ";
}
```

The above will create a query into $insert_query and you just need to send it to database.
The only additional thing you need to figure out is which fields should be quoted and which doesn't. I quoted all of them, since Oracle should be able to cast values correctly - but you need to double check that (I have no Oracle available to check it :) )

The SQL construction I use can be found [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, i will add my working code only that this post is complete and i hope that helps other guys.
here is the code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($router); $i++) {
    $query = "MERGE INTO CORE_INTERFACES USING dual ON "
      // The next row is the match criteria, like If "HOSTNAME" AND "IFINDEX" exist, Then Update else INSERT NEW HOSTNAMES!   
      . "( HOSTNAME = '" . $hostname . "' AND IFINDEX = '" .    t trim($router_interface[0]) . "')" 
      . "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET "
      . "IFNAME = '" . trim($router_interface[1]) . "',IFTYPE = '" . trim(clean_iftype($router_interface[2])) . "',IFADMINSTATUS = '" . trim(clean_output($router_interface[3])) . "',"
      . "LAST_UPDATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "
. "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ("
      . "IF_ID,HOSTNAME,IFINDEX,IFNAME,IFTYPE,IFADMINSTATUS,"
      . "FIRST_SEEN "
      . ") VALUES ("
      . " core_interfaces_seq.nextval, "
      . "'" . $hostname . "',"        //$HOSTNAME
      . "'" . trim($router_interface[0]) . "',"       //ifIndex
      . "'" . trim($router_interface[1]) . "',"       //ifName
      . "'" . trim(clean_iftype($router_interface[2])) . "',"         //ifType
      . "'" . trim(clean_output($router_interface[3])) . "',"         //ifAdminState
      . " CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )";
   $stid = oci_parse($gnedb, $sql);
}
```